# What configure options were used when building binutils?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, toolchain, binutils

I have a version of binutils that was compiled by someone. I need recompile a new binutils with same options.

I know that `gcc -v` prints out the configuration options. So maybe there is any way to read build options for `binutils`?

Comment: Obviously, the easiest way is to get the build file for your distro (e.g. `binutils.spec` for RPM based distros, `PKGBUILD` on Arch, etc...) and check. Otherwise I know of no generic way to check from any of the compiled pieces of binutils itself.

Comment: Hi, it's customized version that was build to /opt.

Comment: Why do you need the same options?

Comment: Because it used for build legacy application in customized toolchain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that support platforms and a binutils version I can check with:

`#ld -V`

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
```

So `ld -V` shows that you should use in `--enable-targets`.

I didn't found any way for options so I tried and check and this is my current set of options:

```
  ./configure --prefix=/opt/dev-tools-4.9            \
--exec-prefix=/opt/dev-tools-4.9       \
 --with-sysroot=/   --enable-multilib     \
 --with-lib-path=/opt/dev-tools-4.9/lib \
 --disable-werror  --enable-shared \
 --with-pkgversion="GNU Binutils for Ubuntu" \
 --enable-targets=x86_64-linux-gnu,i686-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-mingw32,i686-pc-mingw32
make -j $(nproc || grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo|| echo "1") && \
make install
```